# Location mapping not returning on different devices

Tags: android, location, cross-platform, coordinates

I have this code for getting the long and lat coordinates.

```
String bestProvider;
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

     if (location == null){
      }else{
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
        setLat((double)location.getLatitude());
        setLng((double)location.getLongitude());

        }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried using different devices. Some returns a value for lat and long. Some do not. All devices were connected to the internet and gps enabled. Do you guys have any idea on what is causing this? Thanks!

Comment: You might wanna use google's latest offering,Fused location provider to fetch location..Check this [example](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no previous captured location, then getlastknown location does not return any value.So you need to implement the location listener to capture the location.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to getLastKnownLocation which may or may not exists. I suggest you to request single location update. Also remember that lastknownlocation is not necessarily accurate one it may belong to 2 days before. 
dev guide:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

A guide about single update
http://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/current-location-update/